# how to type zip_with with default function

Tags: python, type-hinting

How can I type this function that zips mapping values according to some function?

```
K = TypeVar("K")
U = TypeVar("U")
V = TypeVar("V")
W = TypeVar("W")


def zip_with(
    u: Mapping[K, U],
    v: Mapping[K, V],
    f: Callable[[U, V], W] = lambda u, v: (u, v)
) -> Mapping[K, W]:
    return {k: f(u[k], v[k]) for k in u}
```

I'm getting

```
utils/misc.py:66: error: Incompatible default for argument "f" (default has type "Callable[[U, V], Tuple[U, V]]", argument has type "Callable[[U, V], W]")
utils/misc.py:66: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[U, V]", expected "W")
```

Afaik mypy can't infer type signatures wrt default arguments, but that overloads can help. However, I can't see how you'd do that here without losing type safety somewhere, because if the default for `f` isn't a function, there's no way to create a `W` e.g.

```
@overload
def zip_with(u: Mapping[K, U], v: Mapping[K, V]) -> Mapping[K, Tuple[U, V]]:
    ...


@overload
def zip_with(
    u: Mapping[K, U],
    v: Mapping[K, V],
    f: Callable[[U, V], W]
) -> Mapping[K, W]:
    ...


def zip_with(
    u: Mapping[K, U],
    v: Mapping[K, V],
    f: Optional[Callable[[U, V], W]] = None
) -> Mapping[K, W]:
    if f is None:
        return {k: (u[k], v[k]) for k in u}

    return {k: f(u[k], v[k]) for k in u}
```

gives

```
utils/misc.py:81: error: Value expression in dictionary comprehension has incompatible type "Tuple[U, V]"; expected type "W"
```

Comment: This isn't a very satisfying answer, but frequently when typing tricky stuff like this I end up doing an `Any` or `# type: ignore` in the actual implementation function, and then write lots of unit tests to prove that it actually adheres to the contract specified by the type overloads.

Comment: @Samwise i can achieve pretty close with `@overload` and setting `W` to `Any` in the implementation signature, while maintaining the `lambda` default

Answer (score -1):

The default value for `f` is `lambda u, v: (u, v)`, which has a return value of `Tuple[whatever u is, whatever v is]`, but you specify in they type hint `Callable[[U, V], W]` that the return value should be `W`.

If `Tuple[U, V]` is of type `W`, then your definition of `W` should demonstrate this `W = Tuple[U, V]`

Comment: i don't follow what you mean by "your definition of W should demonstrate this W = Tuple[U, V]". I'm not sure this is possible, because `W` in the return type is presumably bound by the `W` in the input, but that's not bound at all if there's no `f`, so we can't conform to a non-existent type

Comment: > the return type is presumably bound by the W in the input

@joel, I don't understand what you mean by that, as you currently have W defined globally as `W = TypeVar("W")`. This definition contradicts the `Tuple[U, V]` you are returning from the default `lambda u, v: (u, v)`

Comment: i don't think it contradicts it, but that it restricts it, and in a valid way, just as if I passed in that `lambda` as an argument, I'd expect mypy to infer that `W` is a `Tuple[U, V]` in that case

Comment: here's the equivalent code in scala compiling fine https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RFncihTaSHmlmQ9tEXyWsw